# MySQL - Partitioning database or tables by dates for quick cleanup

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning

I have a very large database. One column is the timestamp and every day I want to delete any rows 30 days or older. The problem is that as time goes on, and the database deletes rows and inserts new ones, the new row may be inserted in a position previous occupied by a deleted row creating a fragmented database in respect to the timestamp. When I go to clean up the database, a fragmented database will require a lot of time to clean up because MySQL will have to go through the entire database.

One solution I would like to employ would be to create separate partitions or even separate databases for each day such that each day, a new partition is automatically created to be filled and every 30+ day old partition automatically dropped.

I'm looking into the `PARTITION` command which seems like it retroactively partitions a table. I'd like to do it from the beginning automatically.

Does anyone have any insight on how to do this?

EDIT:
I'm using snort and barnyard to clean up the database. I've been doing something along the lines of this in a cronjob:

```
use YOUR-SNORT-DB-NAME;
DELETE FROM event WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 28 DAY);
DELETE FROM data    USING data    LEFT OUTER JOIN event USING (sid,cid) WHERE event.sid IS NULL;
DELETE FROM iphdr   USING iphdr   LEFT OUTER JOIN event USING (sid,cid) WHERE event.sid IS NULL;
DELETE FROM icmphdr USING icmphdr LEFT OUTER JOIN event USING (sid,cid) WHERE event.sid IS NULL;
DELETE FROM tcphdr  USING tcphdr  LEFT OUTER JOIN event USING (sid,cid) WHERE event.sid IS NULL;
DELETE FROM udphdr  USING udphdr  LEFT OUTER JOIN event USING (sid,cid) WHERE event.sid IS NULL;
DELETE FROM opt     USING opt     LEFT OUTER JOIN event USING (sid,cid) WHERE event.sid IS NULL;
DELETE FROM acid_event USING acid_event LEFT OUTER JOIN event USING (sid,cid) WHERE event.sid IS NULL;
DELETE FROM ag USING acid_ag_alert AS ag LEFT OUTER JOIN event AS e ON ag.ag_sid=e.sid AND ag.ag_cid=e.cid WHERE e.sid IS NULL;
OPTIMIZE TABLE event, data, iphdr, icmphdr, tcphdr, udphdr, opt, acid_event, acid_ag_alert
```

This seems impractical if the database is very large. It doesn't seem to be using indexes either.

I'm not a database expert so I'm wondering how I can modify the schema or cleanup script for performance.

Comment: If your column is indexed, you should not see any performance impacts.

Comment: what make you think you have a fragmented database?

Comment: maybe you should read what is the use of partitions http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6607/how-does-table-partitioning-help

Comment: use partitioning by date - then you can easily just drop partitions with old data, which is instant operation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `PARTITIONing` is useful for purging "old" data from a table.  That is one of the very few uses for `PARTITIONing`.  And use `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))`, not `BY HASH`, etc.  See [*My blog*] for details and sample code for doing the `ALTERs`.  It recommends having about 32 'daily' partitions.

Do not use `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on InnoDB tables; it is almost always not worth the effort.

You do have a composite `INDEX(sid,cid)` on all tables?

If the `DELETEs` on the other tables are too invasive (because of lengthy locks), see [*delete blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) for discussions of less invasive options.